# Is it possible to use “Go Galt” beyond political or business context?

Tags: etymology, verbs, idioms

I came across the expression “Go Galt” in Paul Krugman’s article titled “The Twinkie manifesto” appearing in November 20 New York Times. The phrase appears in the second paragraph of the following interesting remark:

> The data confirm Fortune’s impressions. Between the 1920s and the
>   1950s real incomes for the richest Americans fell sharply, not just
>   compared with the middle class but in absolute terms. According to
>   estimates by the economists Thomas Piketty and Emmanuel Saez, in 1955
>   the real incomes of the top 0.01 percent of Americans were less than
>   half what they had been in the late 1920s, and their share of total
>   income was down by three-quarters.
>
> Strange to say, however, the oppressed executives Fortune portrayed in
>   1955 didn’t **go Galt** and deprive the nation of their talents. On the
>   contrary, if Fortune is to be believed, they were working harder than
>   ever.

I learned from Freedictionary that “Go Galt” means “to cease working in response to punitive taxes as a form of protest.”

What is the origin of “Go Galt”?

Is “Go Galt” used only for describing the business owners’ giving up business to protest heavy tax? Is it the wealthy’s or employers’ counter version of workers’ “strike”?

Can I use “Go Galt” for simply meaning “stop working / business” without a heavy-tax connotation?

Comment: You can read all about John Galt's speech [here](http://www.atlassociety.org/outline-john-galts-speech). I haven't,  but I think it's Too Localised for ELU.

Comment: One would have to be fairly well read to get this reference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Though I’m not familiar with exact definition and standards of “Local-ness” in the ELU, I’m asking (1) the interpretation of the “full-fledged” idiomatic expression in the statement of (2) the world renowned 2008 Nobel Economics prize winner and co-ed columnist of NY-Times talking about (3) the “universal” axiom that high tax on the wealthy doesn’t necessarily demoralize their working motivation by quoting (5) the world-famous Forbes magazine’s statistics in (4) the NY-Times which are read on paper and online by tens of millions people worldwide.

Comment: Continued: It seems to me none of the above factors seems to fit to the name of “local” you like to use.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I’m yet to read John Galt’s speech you kindly informed me of. I’m sure it’s valuable input for furthering my knowledge on this subject and the related expression. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: It does no harm to ask, but to be honest I think it's just NYT columnist Paul Krugman flaunting his cultural credentials. It's certainly not in any meaningful sense an "idiom", but maybe a few people might be prompted to read *Atlas Shrugged* if he repeats the reference often enough.

Comment: Galt means [something completely different](http://www.galttoys.com/) to me!

Comment: @Robusto: If you've read the book, then it would be familiar (true of anything). But the concept was spread pretty widely at least in the news and pundits I heard recently with respect to the recent American election; way oversimplified: rich people not wanting to pay taxes for the use by the leeches, the 47%.

Comment: @Mitch: The point is, literary references aren't like pop-culture references. They're fair game among the literati, and probably we should include readers of the Times in that category. I'm just advising the OP that he shouldn't necessarily expect the average person to understand. I personally wouldn't reference Count Vronsky, or Daisy Buchanan, or Morris Townsend unless I was sure I was addressing someone who was likely to have read widely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without going into all the details, the phrase is patterned after Ayn Rand's science fiction novel "Atlas Shrugged", where the genius creators of progress remove themselves from the wider society to prevent being extorted for the benefit of others. Taxes are only one kind of extortion. To 'Go Galt' can be used metaphorically for any kind of disinvolvement when one is feeling being taken advantage of, but is often used for entrepreneurs and taxes.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question directly: no, not really. It is inherently politically-loaded, because the phrase comes from one of Any Rand's ideological novels.

In the article you quote, it is being used sardonically, along with using the word "oppressed" to refer to highly-paid executives. The term *is* being used in political context, in this case by someone who is [famously critical](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/08/24/opinion/krugman-galt-gold-and-god.html) of the book and the ideology it espouses. Here, he's actually specifically saying that in real life examples, the fictional argument isn't borne out, and is basically using the phrase literally (if negatively), and connected directly to its original source, not in the abstract or as a figure of speech.

Were someone to use this phrase a non-political way, it would probably either be interpreted as actually more political than intended, or it would be taken as a sort of absurdist humor (by applying a heavily-loaded term where it doesn't apply). Probably your audience would just be confused.